# Not enable to connect salesforce account to docusign connect

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm trying to connect my docusign account to my salesforce account, developer version.

My docusing account > preferences > Connect

in this stage, I have to configure salesforce with docusign but eventhough I clic on the link, no configuration appears!!!

Have you any problem how to resolve this? is that due to the trial version??

Answer (score 1):

You will want to configure the DocuSign for Salesforce app inside of Salesforce, that will auto configure you're DocuSign Connect (the feature that pushes information back to Salesforce).

Please see the install and configure section of the guide: 
[Link Here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/docusign-for-salesforce-administrator-guide)